# Как реализовать обработку side эффектов в чистом MVI?

Tags: android

Попал на проект с использованием MVI Orbit. Привык, полюбил. До этого никогда не использовал MVI.
Хочу сделать pet project реализации чистого MVI с использованием ViewModel и Kotlin Flow.
Нигде не могу найти пример как обработать side эффекты. Например нажатие на кнопку приводит к отправке запроса на бэк. Если он вернул 200 -> навигация на след экран. Как это реализовать или подскажите где посмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю в том же Orbit MVI и посмотреть, там довольно просто всё. StateFlow для стейтов и Flow для сайд-эффектов.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]